# Grails 3 on Karaf 4. Anybody has managed to do it?

Tags: grails, osgi, apache-karaf, apache-servicemix

Has anybody managed to run a Grails 3 application on Apache Karaf?

There is a tutorial on how to do it with Grails 2 but it seems very outdated and buggy.

I would appreciate any help even if it is high level bullet points.

Answer (score 1):

Grails has abandoned the support for OSGi long time ago. There were a blog post from G. Rocher cited [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23880545/grails-solution-for-osgi-like-live-modularity):

> "OSGi as a technology is going nowhere and introduces huge amounts of complexity, something which we do not need"

Before some Grails version you could find OSGI-Manifest in grails' jar-files, but definitely not in the 3.x.

Comment: Thanks. Think I agree with the first comment under that question that you linked! Appreciate this is not a straightforward thing to do, but what IS straightforward in OSGI. Was wondering if anybody had any success doing it.